# manual two-column breaks in ioslides

Tags: html, css, r-markdown, ioslides

This is closely related to [my previous question on two-column layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847371/two-column-layouts-in-rstudio-presentations-slidify-pandoc), but I've narrowed my expectations a bit. For the moment I'll skip the "everything and a pony too" request (multiple output formats, etc.), and just focus on getting a *flexible* two-column layout in ioslides format ...

- The [rmarkdown documentation](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ioslides_presentation_format.html) states

  > Note that content will flow across the columns so if you want to have an image on one side and text on the other you should make sure that the image has sufficient height to force the text to the other side of the slide.

A [comment from Sep 2015](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ioslides_presentation_format.html#comment-2248868280) on the same page suggests that two-column breaking is available in the (otherwise inferior, and more or less frozen) `.Rpres` format, but that otherwise

> we have to wait until RStudio incorporates adjustable columns into ioslides

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871611/how-can-i-fix-column-breaks-in-an-rmarkdown-ioslides-presentation) comes close, but the accepted answer is about how to tweak the *content size* until the columns line up as desired.

I'm not a CSS expert, unfortunately ... what would be involved in creating a new layout? I managed to find the source code [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/693b0b1ce2b679c411c4ad4553612e2c943d90f6/inst/rmd/ioslides/ioslides-13.5.1/theme/css/default.css), but it's almost completely opaque to me:

```
/* line 468, ../scss/default.scss */
.columns-2 {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -ms-column-count: 2;
  -o-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424088/css-column-breaks) and [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns/breaks.html) look useful, but it could be a deep rabbit hole ...